# Are there any good tools, specifically code packages to checksum eth validator addresses?

Tags: web3.py, eth-2.0, validators, beacon-chain, checksum

Are there any good tools, specifically code packages to checksum eth validator addresses? They are longer than normal Ethereum addresses, and because of that I find the Web3 python library refuses to checksum them using the toChecksumAddress function. Does anyone know any good tools for this, or any open source implementations I can steal?